# Set componentRestrictions with Google Place Autocomplete API

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I'm making a custom autocomplete field and my goal is to fetch cities from only one country.

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=amsterdam&inputtype=textquery&types=(cities)&fields=geometry,name&language=nl&key=APIKEY`

I've read about the componentRestrictions to bound a specific country. How do I include the param inside the request?

Adding param `&componentRestrictions=nl` doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_autocomplete_requests) for the web service the parameter is `components`:

> - **components** — A grouping of places to which you would like to restrict your results. Currently, you can use components to filter by up to 5 countries. Countries must be passed as a two character, ISO 3166-1 Alpha-2 compatible country code. For example: components=country:fr would restrict your results to places within France. Multiple countries must be passed as multiple country:XX filters, with the pipe character (|) as a separator. For example: components=country:us|country:pr|country:vi|country:gu|country:mp would restrict your results to places within the United States and its unincorporated organized territories.

Example: `components=country:nl`

Full URL:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=amsterdam&inputtype=textquery&types=(cities)&fields=geometry,name&language=nl&components=country:nl&key=APIKEY
```